# C - Order of execution vs local variable initialization

Tags: c

assume I want to measure some timing of a function which is like this

```
void function(void)
{
    Timing_Function(0);

    int var1 = 0;
    int var2 = 1;
    const int var 3 = 5;

    //HERE WE DO SOMETHING

    Timing_Function(1);
}

void function(void)
{
    int var1 = 0;
    int var2 = 1;
    const int var 3 = 5;

    Timing_Function(0);     

    //HERE WE DO SOMETHING

    Timing_Function(1);
}
```

Timing_Function is a function that internally tag the times to be retrieved later by other means, will the two declarations yield different results? i.e. local variable allocation and initialization occurs first no matter where we declare the local variable?

Comment: This depends on the compiler. In general, the two times can be different - the initializations can happen after the call in the first case (although the stack allocation will probably always happen before the time measurement).

Comment: If your timing is so sensitive as to be affected by the local variable initialization, then you're either timing something so short-lasting that it's pointless to time it, or your variable initialization dominates the timing, in which case you *should* be timing it.

Comment: I find it unlikely that any modern compiler would choose to mess with the order like that, even if it sees that Timing_Function doesn't affect var1 and var2 (but I may be wrong). To add to what Roger said, if you're actually trying to do something like this and aren't just curious, just use a program like IDA Pro and look at the top of the function.

Comment: I would but my IDA pro experience doesnt go past the PE format and this is  some embedded aviation product (hence the timing measurements) so I dont even know where to start to decompile.